# Tags: Voltage, current, and power (oh my)

Tags: discussion, tags

Another set of hilarious tags: [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage), [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current), and [power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power)  Almost everything that isn't software could use all of those tags.

- [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage) questions should likely be along the lines of:

  - [voltage-measurement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-measurement)
  - [voltage-regulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-regulator)
  - [level-shifting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/level-shifting)
  - [high-voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-voltage)
  - [undervoltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undervoltage)
  - or removed entirely (80-99% of the time)
- [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current)

  - [current-measurement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-measurement)
  - [current-source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-source)
  - or removed entirely
- [power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) <strike>and [supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supply) ([see also](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/usefulness-of-the-supply-tag?rq=1))</strike>

  - [power-supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply)
  - [low-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-power), (almost as bad, as it's subjective and varies a lot across fields and skill-levels.)
  - [line-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-power) (just made that tag, is there already one?  mains/ac-power/wall-power...)
  - [power-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-electronics) (this could be fraught with peril)
  - or removed entirely
- [charge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charge)

  - [battery-charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging)
  - or removed entirely
- [circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit)

  - [circuit-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-analysis)
  - or removed entirely

Thoughts on removing/retagging questions with P/I/V as they appear?

Their physical counterparts [capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capacitor), [resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resistor), [inductor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inductor), or other circuit elements are also very prone to abuse, but questions are generally focused on them in some manner.

Comment: Apparently I'm guilty of this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7117/how-far-apart-should-pcb-traces-be-for-mains-isolation -- which should probably have my new `line-power` tag in lieu of `power`

Comment: hmm, that's quite a few questions and they'd all have to be manually retagged, as this isn't a batch rename scenario

Comment: @Jeff, yes it would be a pain, and I like to refrain from polluting the main page with simple retags (a problem [others have as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)), hence my concession "as they appear" :P

Comment: This is a good point. If a solution is not accepted soon we will have to introduce a tag 'Discussion-Voltage-Current-Power"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would call [line-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-power) [mains-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains-power), but that may be a local thing. Is it *"line power"* across the US?
- I like the tag [low-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-power), and it appears to have been used correctly so far. May need an edit or two every now and then; <strike>maybe even a wiki if one of us ever earns it.</strike> *My goodness, there are plenty of users that can create this wiki, even me! Guess I should get off my butt!*
- The [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage) tags will be quite the operation. Will have to just do a few every day to spread out the damage. This is how I've been doing the [meta tags](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/115/2118).

*Just edited [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/9346/revisions) with this note:*

> ```
> Phasing out the tags [voltage] and [current]: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/372/2118
> ```

Comment: Yes, low-power is an important design requirement in many circuits.  The requirement is usually "as low as possible" so specific power levels are not relevant to its use.

Comment: I agree with @tyblu about mains-power because thats what its referred to in the UK.

Comment: Around here people typically call it "wall power" or "grid power". I prefer "mains power" over "line power".