# Usefulness of the "supply" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Shouldn't the tag [supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supply) be disallowed? It's almost always used together with the [power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) tag, instead of using the [power-supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply). In any case it never refers to supplies in the logistics sense of the word. I changed all current 8 occurrences to [power-supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply).

Answer (score 3):

You're right, that was not a good tag.  Thanks for taking care of it!

On the subject of whether or not it should be disallowed, now that you've removed every instance of it, users will need to have the privilege to create new tags for it to reappear.  It's unlikely to come back.

For now, it's probably safe to assume that it's not going to come back.  If it becomes a problem, *then* we can ask to have it added to the blacklist.

Thanks again for your cleanup efforts!

Comment: A year or so on, this came back on 37 questions.  Please KIWF.

Answer (score 1):

I have made [supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supply) a synonym for [power-supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) .