# Tag Cleanup - Current

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

Tag cleanup TLDR: Let's get rid of the [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) tag.

**Overview:**

Following up with [this question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372/tags-voltage-current-and-power-oh-my) on broad overused tags, I would like to see how people feel about cleaning up some of the really useless tags that we have, such as [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current), [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage), [power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power), and [circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit). Generally speaking, one tag should not apply to the vast majority of questions on this site otherwise it doesn't add any organizing value. I would like to go through each of these four tags and figure out a long-term strategy for managing these tags.

**The [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) tag:**

Currently (ha!) there are 512 questions that are tagged [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current). Of those 512, only 19 are *only* tagged current, the rest have other tags. This means that there are relatively few questions that *must* be retagged in any case. This means that if we just nuked the tag, the untagged results would be easy to deal with.

**What do we do without a [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) tag!?!?**

There are a few different use cases for the [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) tag:

- It's used just to add another tag to the question
- [circuit-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-analysis) (Covers most of the homework and class problem questions)
- [current-measurement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-measurement)
- [current-limiting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-limiting)
- [constant-current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant-current)
- [current-source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-source) and [current-sink](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sink)

**Proposed Actions:**

Let's nuke the [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) tag (administratively delete it from all questions in a way that does not impact the front page), and blacklist it so that it doesn't come back. Future questions will not be able to use it, and we will need to retag 19 or so questions, which will not put a huge load on the front page.

**Why Nuking?**

*Ideally*, all the questions tagged [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) would be manually retagged. At 500+ tagged questions, this would take a long time and pollute the front page with minor edits. Additionally, new questions will be added that misuse the tag. It is possible to blacklist a tag so it can't be used on new questions, but it will cause edits to existing questions with the tag to fail (apparently in a way that will cause a lot of confusion). Nuking the tag (administratively removing the tag from all questions that use it) is probably the most realistic option for big tags, but we *are* basically deleting information about those questions.

Comment: For reference, you can use the StackExchange Data Explorer to find questions with only one tag with this query: http://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/142695/questions-with-only-one-tag#resultSets

Comment: I support this proposal, but I think some newbies might be confused when they can't use the tag when asking a question about current as a concept, or calculating current in a circuit, etc.

Comment: @JYelton *Ideally* they would be using a more descriptive tag, such as [tag:circuit-analysis] or [tag:homework] (just kidding, don't tag things homework).

Comment: Just saw this tag resurface as the only tag on a pretty trivial question, did we not do anything with it?

Answer (score 6):

Having a "current" tag is about as useful as having an "electrons" tag.

Answer (score -3):

If it's not broken, don't fix it.

Current is a [very] fundamental thing.
I have a few undergraduate EE texts.  Here's an excerpt from the table of contents of one of them (Schwarz & Oldham)

> 1. Principles of electrical circuits
>      1.1 Electrical quantities
>      charge / current / voltage / power

Besides, the 19 questions that have only the current tag is not a negligible number.

Don't nuke it.  Please.
[we could find you some other tag to nuke]

Comment: My point is that it is so fundamental that it could apply to almost every question. That doesn't doesn't make for a useful tag.

Comment: You are looking at this from a taxonomization standpoint.   Look at it from an EE standpoint.

Comment: I'm looking at it from a taxonomy standpoint because we're talking about an organization scheme (tags).

Comment: @W5VO  Do you have access to statistics on how much people search by a given tag?

Comment: In terms of internal search results, I don't have any information. From Google searches, nobody is searching for "current" and coming to our site.

Comment: Just to be clear, we're not saying that we won't answer questions on current, and you'll still find a whole bunch of questions about current if you type `current` into the search bar. You mentioned "If it's not broken, don't fix it." but from my perspective/opinion, it *is* broken. For a comparable example, would you want to keep a tag called "length"?

Comment: @W5VO  I would keep the tag "length" and "distance" on forum where it's a principal quantity, like geometry or topography, yes.