# Blacklist electronics tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blacklist-request

As discussed [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/shouldnt-we-disallow-adding-deprecated-tags), this tag is deprecated since it isn't adding information and should apply to all questions here. @Kevin Vermeer♦ said to create a per-tag discussion to delete them.

Comment: The tag needs to die, but many of the questions [tagged electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics) have other bad tags, bad content, or only the electronics tag.  The process is (1) Edit questions which need to be retagged, (both the post and the tags!) (2) Burninate (delete in bulk) the questions which are otherwise in good shape (3) Wait a while, and, if the tag returns after being completely deleted, blacklist it.   This should therefore be a burnination request. I'll edit my previous post to be more clear.

Comment: Is there a way to search for those tagged with electronics only?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  There are only 3 pages, though, I scanned the list (which took about 60 seconds), and there appear to be 11 in total.  Those will get the [tag:untagged] tag if we burninate it, which makes them easy to find.

Comment: Hold up!  You're overwhelming the front page.  I appreciate your good intentions, but we need to make sure we don't push off other, more important content.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer: Any particular reason to edit the question in (1)? Most of the questions aren't hurt by the tag. Or are you just saying it should be reviewed to make sure it makes sense with the new tag?

Comment: The primary reason for asking you to stop is because the pace of edits you are working at is overwhelming the purpose of the front page.  We want meaningful edits to be bumped them for peer review, and make sure that new content can also be reviewed.  At the pace you were going, you might as well be a machine, and we don't need to waste (1) your time and (2) our front page space with machine-like editing.

Comment: When I suggested that we review the content, I was thinking of tags like [tag:careers], [tag:beginners], [tag:homework], and [tag:learn]. Some of those are either off-topic or likely to be poor quality, and need edits or closure/deletion.  Also, if a question is closed, it doesn't need to be bumped by an edit.  We'll end up burninating and blacklisting [tag:electronics].

Comment: Stopped the edits. I guess when I checked to see that a tag edit pushed it to the front, I must have forgotten to refresh.

Comment: Thank you.  I've pinged a dev to do some burnination.

Comment: @kevin do you agree with the state of the homework tag? see comment on below answer..

Comment: @JeffAtwood - Yes.  I'm decidedly on the "No homework tag" side of the fence, our users do a good job of answering questions which are obviously homework by teaching instead of giving the answer directly, and we get enough hobbyists trying to learn that we inflict this tag and its results on self-learners.  Burninate, please.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I burninated

[careers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/careers), [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics), [beginner](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner), [homework](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)

Let me know what else needs to be done.

Comment: I reviewed the homework tag; most have other tags and the one that doesn't isn't a good question. Suggest "burniate" it too.

Comment: ok, that is done!

Comment: Another question got added with this tag. Suggest black-listing it. It's such an obvious tag that it will keep getting it added unless we ban it.