# Remove electrical-engineering tag from all questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions with the [electrical-engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-engineering) tag presently (9/2011) don't benefit by the tag; it doesn't tell me anything new. I expect we will wish to blacklist it, but think we should try this first. Related disucssion on disallowing such general tags [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/shouldnt-we-disallow-adding-deprecated-tags).

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is done -- note that you can use the `[tag:tagname]` syntax as documented in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tags